# How to turn long back into wide format in pandas

Tags: pandas, altair

I have some data in long format.

[image]

I want to transform the categories columns to columns so I can plot in Altair. Can I do this directly in Altair or is there a simple line pandas to transform?

Comment: It would be most helpful to have a piece of your data (not a screen-shot).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1ll1a85nitrmx7/data_long.csv?dl=0 Does this work?

Comment: Yes, it does. But what is your expected output? Could you give a minimal example of what should be the wanted output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't provide any output. However, I suppose you are looking for `pivot_table` with `aggfunc='first'`:

```
records = df.groupby(['to_drop', 'categories']).cumcount().rename('records')
out = (df.pivot_table(index=['to_drop', records], columns='categories',
                      values='values', aggfunc='first')
         .ffill().reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None))
print(out)

# Output
      to_drop  records Admissions             Area  Gender Number of admissions per 100,000 population  Year
0           0        0       1860     Amber Valley    Male                                        2810  2019
1           0        1        780     Amber Valley  Female                                        1110  2019
2           0        2       1600     Amber Valley    Male                                        2470  2018
3           0        3        680     Amber Valley  Female                                         980  2018
4           0        4       1500     Amber Valley    Male                                        2350  2017
...       ...      ...        ...              ...     ...                                         ...   ...
2659      332        3       3310  North Yorkshire  Female                                         960  2018
2660      332        4       7660  North Yorkshire    Male                                        2360  2017
2661      332        5       2920  North Yorkshire  Female                                         850  2017
2662      332        6       7790  North Yorkshire    Male                                        2450  2016
2663      332        7       2740  North Yorkshire  Female                                         810  2016

[2664 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the data structure, I suspect `Area` should be handled differently than other categories. Aggregating with `first` will discard most of your data.

You could aggregate with `list` and explode to keep all entries:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data_long.csv', index_col=0)

df['Area'] = df[df['categories']=='Area']['values']
df['Area'].ffill(inplace=True)
df = (df[df['categories']!='Area']
        .pivot_table(columns='categories', values='values', index='Area', aggfunc=list)
        .apply(pd.Series.explode)
).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
categories  Area Admissions  Gender Number of admissions per 100,000 population  Year
0           Adur        780    Male                                        2380  2019
1           Adur        280  Female                                         790  2018
2           Adur        730    Male                                        2270  2018
3           Adur        310  Female                                         870  2018
4           Adur        670    Male                                        2090  2017
...          ...        ...     ...                                         ...   ...
2659        York       1110  Female                                        1080  2018
2660        York       2590    Male                                        2910  2017
2661        York        980  Female                                         970  2017
2662        York       2410    Male                                        2740  2016
2663        York        990  Female                                         980  2016

[2664 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: *Aggregating with first will discard most of your data.*. No I create a subgroup of records so there is only one instance for each index. Nothing is discarded.

Comment: You're right I just noticed your Edit ;-) +1