# How to make an ugly plot in Altair more useful

Tags: pandas, altair

Thank you first and foremost to @corralien (https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien) for helping me work up a solution to this problem

[How to turn long back into wide format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364099/how-to-turn-long-back-into-wide-format-in-pandas)

I've tried to use Altair to graph the data.

##### Convert 'Year' column to a string data type

```
out['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(out['Year'], format='%Y').dt.year.astype(str)
```

##### Filter the data based on the selected area

```
area_selector = alt.selection_single(fields=['Area'], bind='legend', name='area_selector')
```

##### Create the base chart with x-axis as 'Year' and area filter

```
base = alt.Chart(out).encode(
    x=alt.X('Year:O', title='Year'),
    color=alt.Color('Gender:N', title='Gender'),
    tooltip=['Year', 'Admissions', 'Number of admissions per 100,000 population']
)
```

##### Create the chart for admissions

```
admissions_chart = base.mark_line().encode(
    y=alt.Y('Admissions:Q', title='Admissions'),
).properties(
    title='Admissions'
).add_selection(
    area_selector
).transform_filter(
    area_selector
).interactive()
```

##### Create the chart for admissions per 100,000 people

```
per_100k_chart = base.mark_line().encode(
    y=alt.Y('Number of admissions per 100,000 population:Q', title='Admissions per 100,000'),
).properties(
    title='Admissions per 100,000'
).transform_filter(
    area_selector
).interactive()
```

##### Combine the charts using a repeated chart with shared x-axis

```
chart = alt.hconcat(admissions_chart, per_100k_chart, title='Comparison of Admissions and Admissions per 100,000')
```

##### Configure the chart to be more compact

```
chart.configure_view(
    height=200,
    width=400
)
```

But I don't think it is informative. Any suggestions on how to make it a little more informative.

And confused why the filter doesn't work.

[image]